# OpenProcess Access is denied for some users

Tags: c++, windows

I have an application that opens another non-system 32-bit process and attempts to get a list of its loaded modules with `EnumProcessModulesEx` and path of each module with `GetModuleFileNameEx`. It works well in my development environment (Windows 10) and for many users that have tested the application. However, **for some users** (two users, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10) the OpenProcess() function fails with ***Access is denied*** (error code 5).

I am opening the process with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ`. Opening the process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` works, but then `EnumProcessModulesEx` will fail. According to my testing, both `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` and `PROCESS_VM_READ`, if used alone, will fail OpenProcess() for users with the mentioned issue. Also I believe `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ` is required for `EnumPorcessModulesEx`, so trying with less access rights is not an option.

However, when the application is executed with "**Run as administrator**", this problem no longer occurs. OpenProcess() works and also the application works as expected.

**The problem**

```
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processid);
```

Works for most users, but returns error code 5, access is denied for some users of the application.

**Partial solution**

...is to run the application as administrator. OpenProcess() then works well.

**Question**

Why is access denied for some users when the application is executed without "Run as administrator"? Is there an alternative way to get a list of modules of another process without executing my application as administrator?

Comment: What is the other process? which user is it running as?

Comment: Clearly the user doesn't have sufficient rights.

Comment: @immibis, the other process is an old game and both my application and the target process are running as same user that is in administrator group.

Comment: It is likely that the target process is running "as administrator", perhaps because the Windows compatibility engine decided that it needed administrator privilege to run properly, or because the user at some point in the past configured it to do so.  If I understand your scenario rightly, the simplest solution would probably be for your process to launch the game on the user's behalf, I think that will prevent it from being unexpectedly elevated.  (At any rate when you launch a process yourself you get a handle with full access rights.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Indeed, you were absolutely correct. The target process does want administrator privileges for users with the issue, the executable icon has blue/yellow shield. What confuses me is that for most other people the game does not ask to be run as administrator. I went into the executable's properties, and it was not checked to be run as administrator, however for some reason it still wants so.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not clear on the details or I'd post an answer, but I *think* that Windows can store compatibility settings for an executable (including "always elevate") somewhere in the registry.  (There might be existing questions about this either here or on Super User or Server Fault.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the **AdjustTokenPrivileges** API?

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/10125867/ExitWindowsEx-AdjustTokenPrivileges-to-SE-SHUTDOWN-NAME.html

By default, even if the process is running elevated (as an administrator), some privileges are still disabled process-wise. To enable them, we need to call **OpenProcessToken**, **LookupPrivilegeValue** and **AdjustTokenPrivileges** APIs.

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights), SeDebugPrivilege (macro **SE_DEBUG_NAME**) is needed to do ReadProcessMemory (which requires PROCESS_VM_READ access).